# Handling transient exceptions when iterating over a Service Fabric ReliableDictionary

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

Let's say I have a method that iterates over all rows in a `ReliableDictionary` like so:

```
var reliableDictionary = await StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<TKey, TValue>>(dictionaryName);

using (var tx = StateManager.CreateTransaction())
{
    var enumerable = await reliableDictionary.CreateEnumerableAsync(tx);
    var enumerator = enumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator();
    while (await enumerator.MoveNextAsync(cancellationToken))
    {
        // Read enumerator.Current and do something with the value 
        // (not writing back to the dictionary here)
    }
}
```

How could I handle retrying of transient exceptions here (i.e., `TimeoutException`, `FabricNotReadableException` and `FabricTransientException`)?

The code documentation for the enumerator is unclear on what exceptions can be thrown on each method. Which methods can throw these transient exceptions - `CreateTransaction`, `CreateEnumerableAsync`, `GetAsyncEnumerator`, `MoveNextAsync` and `enumerator.Current`?

If a transient exception is thrown from one of these methods, how should I retry?

If a transient exception is thrown from `MoveNextAsync` or `enumerator.Current`, can I retry it without aborting the while loop, or should I create a whole new transaction and start enumerating from the beginning again?

Comment: See [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/872099/Transient-Exception-Handling) article; it has lots of great information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-work-with-reliable-collections describes working with Reliable Collections under transactions. Basically you should do the following:

```
retry:

try {
   // Create a new Transaction object for this partition
   using (ITransaction tx = base.StateManager.CreateTransaction()) {
      // AddAsync takes key's write lock; if >4 secs, TimeoutException
      await m_dic.AddAsync(tx, key, value, cancellationToken);

      await tx.CommitAsync();
   }
}
catch (TimeoutException) {
   await Task.Delay(100, cancellationToken); goto retry;
}
```

The sample usage here is with goto statement, but any retry handling should work.

You can modify the timeout if you know your transaction will take longer (as it will in your case) but you should consider the impact it might have on your solution. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-reliable-collections

> The default time-out is 4 seconds for all the Reliable Collection APIs. Most users should not override this.

And

> Do not use `TimeSpan.MaxValue` for time-outs. Time-outs should be used to detect deadlocks.

As for the other exception types you mention (`FabricNotReadableException` and `FabricTransientException`), you could/should retry those as well. They are commonly thrown by Service Fabric when something changes in the configuration of your service(s), like a change in primary or if you for some reason end up talking to a secondary. *Most cases* it should be retryable. `FabricTransientException` is just a base class for a number of exceptions that can occur in the communication with Reliable Services and it indicates an exception that *could* go away if retried.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34006599/1062217) describes `FabricNotReadableException`, for instance, there are some cases where you need to re-resolve your service in the client to end up on another replica.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should have made it more clear in the question that I was really looking for guidance on what to do when an exception is thrown while enumerating a reliable dictionary - should I start enumerating again from the beginning, or attempt to keep going from the current point? The sample you provided suggested that I should just retry the entire transaction (i.e., start enumerating from the beginning again)?

Comment: Yeah, as far as I can see, starting over is really the only option here. The TimeOutException will likely occur when you try to initiate the transaction, while the other transient exceptions could be because your replica changed role or failed (or some other action that changes it's role). Either of these could mean that the data you are looking at or trying to read is no longer accurate. Retrying the entire transaction is likely the only thing that makes sense in most cases.