# What "Transient Exceptions" are handled by ServiceProxy?

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

Looking at the [Service Remoting article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting#remoting-exception-handling), I can see the following:

> If Transient Exceptions occurs, proxy retries the call.

What specifically is considered a "Transient Exception" by the proxy?

In the past we've handled Timeout, InvalidOperation ([See here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/be0af246-be89-4078-9d75-84f73c7d4b32/invalidoperationexception-transaction-has-already-committed-or-rolled-back?forum=AzureServiceFabric)), FabricNotReadableException ([See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33960481/what-does-the-fabricnotreadableexception-mean-and-how-should-we-respond-to-it)) and FabricTransientExceptions ourselves for operations on Reliable Collections - Should we be doing the same for our interactions with other Services using SF Remoting?

As an example:

```
//Get Proxy 
var serviceProxy = ServiceProxy.Create<IService>(GetServiceUri(), GetPartitionKey());
//Make Call to method which has no internal handling for transient SF failures... 
//Should this be wrapped with a retry policy?
var result = await serviceProxy.GetAll();
```

Comment: It is probably somewhere [in the code](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-services-and-actors-dotnet/blob/develop/src/Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting/Client/ServiceRemotingExceptionHandler.cs#L118) so maybe get the code and so some digging.

Comment: @PeterBons Thanks! I didn't realise this had all been open sourced... Looks like it's covering FabricNotPrimaryException when the Primary has moved as well as all instances of FabricTransientException and FabricNotReadableException

Answer (score 0):

As per the  exception handler for remoting ([ServiceRemotingExceptionHandler.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/service-fabric-services-and-actors-dotnet/blob/develop/src/Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting/Client/ServiceRemotingExceptionHandler.cs#L118)), it appears that the Proxy will handle the following errors:

- FabricNotPrimaryException when the Primary has moved
- FabricTransientException exceptions
- FabricNotReadableException exceptions

You may still wish to handle Timeout exceptions yourself.