# Accessing Service Fabric service state during cancellation

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

I have a Service Fabric cluster hosting an 'Orchestrator'-type service which spins up and shuts down other Stateful services to do work, using `FabricClient.ServiceManagementClient`'s CreateServiceAsync and DeleteServiceAsync methods.

The work involves processing messages which are stored for a short time within a `ReliableConcurrentQueue`.

I'm trying to handle the graceful shutdown of these services via the `CancellationToken` by ensuring that the queue is completely drained of messages before the service is deleted, but have found that the service's access to the `ReliableConcurrentQueue` is revoked once the `CancellationToken` is cancelled.

For example, calling `StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<T>()` from a callback registered with the CancellationToken, results in a FabricNotReadableException, containing the message "Primary state manager is currently not readable".

Reading around, it seems this is expected behaviour:

> "In Service Fabric, when a Primary is demoted, one of the first things
>   that happens is that write access to the underlying state is revoked."
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-lifecycle

Also, the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33960481/what-does-the-fabricnotreadableexception-mean-and-how-should-we-respond-to-it) suggest that FabricNotReadableException is often a transient issue, and affected calls can be retried. This doesn't seem to be the case in this example; multiple retries at various frequencies/delays all seem to fail the same way.

Is there a way to guarantee that everything in the queue is processed using the combination of Stateful services, Reliable Collections and CancellationTokens? Or should I be looking into storage outside of what Service Fabric can provide?

Answer (score 0):

Consider performing the queue item processing inside `RunAsync`.

Stopping / changing the role of a service causes the `CancellationToken` passed to `RunAsync` to be cancelled.

Once that happens, you need to make sure that you only exit that method when the queue depth is 0.

Also, once this cancellation is requested, you should probably stop allowing new items to be enqueued.

Comment: That's how I thought it should work too - sadly, once the CancellationToken passed to RunAsync has been cancelled, operations on the StateManager throw FabricNotReadableException even if you're calling them from within RunAsync.